# JSF - Validator personalizado executado, nenhum problema encontrado, mas fluxo de execução não chega no Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, xhtml

Criei um Custom Validador, referenciei-o em um `<h:inputText>`, o Validador é executado, nenhuma exceção é levantada, mas o fluxo de execução não chega no Managed Bean.

Onde devo estar errando?

```html
<h:inputText id="cpf" size="18" maxlength="14" rendered="true" value="#{managedBean.usuario.CPF}">
  <c:validator validatorId="cpfValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

```js
package br.web.jsf.validators;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

import br.util.BibliotecaMetodos;

@FacesValidator("cpfValidator")
public class CPFValidator implements Validator {
 
 @Override
 public void validate(FacesContext pFacesContext, UIComponent pUiComponent, Object pObject) throws ValidatorException {
  String cpf = (String) pObject;
  
  if ( !BibliotecaMetodos.isCPFvalido(cpf) ) {
   FacesMessage mensagem = new FacesMessage("O CPF é Nulo ou Inválido.");
   mensagem.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
   
   throw new ValidatorException(mensagem);
  }
 }
 
}
```

Comment: de uma olhada no console, talvez voce esteja com problema de validação em outro campo, ou algum outro problema, provavelmente deve aparecer algum erro no console, qualquer coisa que não conseguir identificar o erro no console, edite sua pergunte e poste o conteúdo aqui no forum

Comment: Eis a questão. O Console não imprime uma linha sequer após a execução do Validador, não deixando pista nenhuma. :/

Comment: Descobri uma outra validação com problemas, mas que estava silenciosamente parando a execução ¬¬. Fica a dica, confiram outras Validações

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria que voce se tocasse, nem sempre sua validação customizada é o problema pode haver outras validações e essas estão causando o problema.